# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-function

How to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)dx$$
I didn't get it by partial integration,Any help is appreciated.

I still can't solve this integral. That's a good question. Why doesn't anyone answer it?

Comment: Where did you see this integral?

Comment: @pisco125 I'm sorry. It's been a long time. I forgot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Through $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$ and symmetry we get that the given integral equals 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2+\sin(x)}{2+2\sin(x)}\right)\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{2+z}{2+2z}\right)\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
hence it is enough to compute
$$ \int_{3/4}^{1}\frac{\arctan(u)\,du}{(2u-1)\sqrt{4u-3}}\quad\text{or}\quad \int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{3+v^2}{4}\right)\frac{dv}{1+v^2}.$$
This can be done through integration by parts and the dilogarithms machinery, but the final outcome is not really nice. At least, not the one I got, but maybe I missed some crucial simplification. Anyway, the approach just outlined tends to work pretty well for similar [Ahmed-like](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5169) integrals.

Comment: I don't really understand this step?

Comment: @JamesJ: which step is troubling you?

Comment: What's the connection between the first definite integral and my integral?

Comment: @JamesJ: they are the same. You integral equals $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\frac{1-\cos x}{2+\sin x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\frac{2+\sin x}{2+2\sin x}\,dx$$

Comment: But that's what mine is:$\frac{1-\sin x}{2+\cos x}$?

Comment: @JamesJ: this is what you wrote: $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)dx$$ and there isn't a $\frac{1-\sin x}{2+\cos x}$ in there. Anyway, the above approach applies to that case, too.

Comment: My meaning is $\int_{0}^{\pi}\arctan \left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan \left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan \left(\frac{1-\sin x}{2+\cos x}\right)dx$

Comment: @JamesJ: $\sin(\pi -x)=\sin(x)$ and $\cos(\pi -x)=-\cos(x)$. This is what I mean by *symmetry* above.

Comment: I maybe know what you mean now, thank you very much.

Comment: But how about the last integral?

Comment: @JamesJ: have a look at my answer to this similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359461/how-do-i-evaluate-this-integral-int-frac1-sqrt1-x2-arctan-frac?rq=1) for grasping *how* to apply the dilogarithms machinery to the computation of the last integral.